# How to hide api response from user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, backend, next.js

I'm using react as a frontend and express/next.js as backend/api. They 'communicate' via GET/POST requests and JSON data responses. Everytime the site gets rendered server-side, there is no api data in chrome debugger. But when the user routes client-side through the page - it calls the api client-side and you can see all the data that comes from the api (mongoDB). I always wanted to know if its possible to hide the JSON data from the user. I have restaurant site that gets data of many restaurants in JSON data, so its like publishing the data of the mongodb to the client.

On popular sites that use react or other frameworks I can't see the api data in chrome debugger.

I have a site where the user can set some filters and then go to a results site that shows the filtered restaurants. So how do I always send the api calls server side?

Comment: No.  You can't hide it.  Anything your client requests from the server via an Ajax call is available for anyone (with a small amount of tech savvy) to see.  If you don't want that JSON data to be seen, you have to design your app differently where it isn't being requested from your server like that.  Perhaps you would do server-side rendering so only the HTML comes to the client.

Comment: You can't hide the requests, but you can encrypt the data if you really wanted to.  I don't see the point though, if the server is sending the user some data, that user should be able to observe that data.  If not, why is the server sending it?

Comment: Don't send the client data that you don't want the client to have full and unrestricted access to.

Comment: This is simply how single-page applications work. If you need to hide all that, consider using a server-side only solution that only renders final output, if that's possible for your use case. Alternatively, if your real issue here is that you're hitting 3rd party APIs directly from the client, you would want to proxy those requests through your own backend.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which you are sending to the client side as the response can be retrieved by the client(customer) either in chrome debugger tabs or by making a direct query to that API Programmatically.

Only good way to do this is to restrict the API from giving away the restricted data. If you just want to keep the data away from debugger tab, you can do a full page load instead of an ajax.

Comment: Ok, and how do I give the parameters to the page that gets the results? The only way is query parameters like: page.com/?parameter1=xyz&parameter2=abc, right?

Comment: Do you mean query parameters or POST parameters?

Comment: I mean the info to the page on what it has to call from the api, like filter settings and stuff like that

Comment: You can pass those setting as the query parameters to the page. All those parameters need to be added after a "?" in the URL.

Comment: do redux states stay when doing a full page load?
like that: I store the filter settings in redux on page 1 and then do full page load to page 2 and use that redux state?

Comment: @panskehanske ask a new question.  don't keep tacking on new questions here.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably need to recheck and recode your program to do server-side rendering rather than client-side rendering.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).